# difference between windows os refresh and ubuntu reload?

Tags: 14.04, windows, nautilus

I thought that Linux does not have refresh option. but I figured out that a few weeks ago. Ubuntu has a reload option in nautilus explorer. my question is why do we need refresh or reload option. what is difference between them ?. then when I rightclick on desktop. ubuntu does not show refresh or reload option. why ? please help me guys to better understand.

Comment: To show new files created by other programs.

Comment: There is no difference. Those two words mean the same thing.

Comment: okay. but when i rightclick on desktop. ubuntu does not show any refresh or reload option . why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `F5` to refresh or reload.